# protobuf Android import files

Tags: android, protocol-buffers

More file import  build will go wrong，android build.gradle:

```
Cause: protoc: stdout: . stderr: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\WxDemo\app\build\extracted-include-protos\main: warning: directory does not exist.
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\WxDemo\app\src\debug\proto: warning: directory does not exist.
./app/src/main/java/proto/protobuf.proto: Backslashes, consecutive slashes, ".", or ".." are not allowed in the virtual path
./app/src/main/java/proto/protobuf_request_response.proto: Backslashes, consecutive slashes, ".", or ".." are not allowed in the virtual path
protobuf_main.proto: Import "./app/src/main/java/proto/protobuf.proto" was not found or had errors.
protobuf_main.proto: Import "./app/src/main/java/proto/protobuf_request_response.proto" was not found or had errors.
protobuf_main.proto:10:14: "CMD_SERVICE" seems to be defined in "protobuf.proto", which is not imported by "protobuf_main.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
```

`Build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.haha.dot.chat"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/main/java'
            }
            proto {
                srcDir 'src/main/proto'
                include '**/*.proto'
            }
        }
    }

    //android studio默认so文件加载目录为:src/main/jniLibs
    //如在module的build.gradle按照如下方式,自定义了so文件加载目录请确保对应目录下只有armeabi目录
        sourceSets {
            main{
                jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
            }
        }
}



protobuf {
    //这里配置protoc编译器
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0'
    }
    plugins {
        javalite {
            // The codegen for lite comes as a separate artifact
            artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0'
        }
    }
    //这里配置生成目录，编译后会在build的目录下生成对应的java文件
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            all()*.plugins {
                javalite { }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0-alpha1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'

    implementation 'io.netty:netty-all:4.1.16.Final'
    implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.0'
//    implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.2.0' //依赖的protobuf-java lib
}
```